# i want this big red coloured div to follow my custom cursor from its original and fixed position just like a line

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      body {
        overflow: hidden;
        perspective: 500px;
        perspective-origin: top;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: black;
        position: relative;
      }

      .cursor {
        position: fixed;
        width: 5rem;
        height: 5rem;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: black;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px white;
        z-index: 11;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform: translateZ(100px) rotateX(-0deg);
      }

      .follow_cursor {
        position: absolute;
        background: red;
        width: 5rem;
        height: auto;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 10%;
        left: 80%;
        right: 0;
        transform-origin: top;
      }

      .follow_cursor::after {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        top: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: white;
        z-index: 3;
        width: 5rem;
        height: 5rem;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- this div need to be fixed -->
    <div class="follow_cursor"></div>
    <div class="cursor"></div>
    
    <script>
      let cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
      let main = document.querySelector(".main");
      let follow = document.querySelector(".follow_cursor");
      document.onmousemove = (e) => {
        let x = e.pageX;
        let y = e.pageY;
        cursor.style.left = x + "px";
        cursor.style.top = y + "px";

        follow.style.height = y + "px";

        let check = parseFloat(x);

        follow.style.transform = `rotateZ(-${check / 10}deg) `;
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
      perspective: 500px;
      perspective-origin: top;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      background: black;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .cursor {
      position: fixed;
      width: 5rem;
      height: 5rem;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background: black;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px white;
      z-index: 11;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform: translateZ(100px) rotateX(-0deg);
    }
    
    .follow_cursor {
      position: absolute;
      background: red;
      width: 5rem;
      height: auto;
      z-index: 2;
      top: 10%;
      left: 80%;
      right: 0;
      transform-origin: top;
    }
    
    .follow_cursor::after {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      top: 100%;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: white;
      z-index: 3;
      width: 5rem;
      height: 5rem;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- this div need to be fixed -->
  <div class="follow_cursor"></div>
  <div class="cursor"></div>
</body>
<script>
  let cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
  let main = document.querySelector(".main");
  let follow = document.querySelector(".follow_cursor");
  document.onmousemove = (e) => {
    let x = e.pageX;
    let y = e.pageY;
    cursor.style.left = x + "px";
    cursor.style.top = y + "px";

    follow.style.height = y + "px";

    let check = parseFloat(x);

    follow.style.transform = `rotateZ(-${check / 10}deg) `;
  };
</script>

</html>
```

As you can see the red-colored div is aligned on the right side of the container which needs to follow my custom cursor but behaving differently.

Comment: unclear what it is supposed to do exactly... You want the line to connect to the cursor?

Comment: using translate3D for positioning will be faster and smoother. I wouldn't change height on the rect, either, but use scale. Then do the math for the angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this snippet using transform and formulas to determine the correct angle and size.  It uses SQRT(w^2 + h^2) to get distance (height of rectangle, which is divided by 2 because you have a double height red/white object).   It uses arc tangent to determine the angle from the cartessian points.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
      perspective: 500px;
      perspective-origin: top;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      background: black;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .cursor {
      position: fixed;
      width: 5rem;
      height: 5rem;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background: black;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px white;
      z-index: 11;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform: translateZ(100px) rotateX(-0deg);
    }
    
    .follow_cursor {
      position: absolute;
      background: red;
      width: 5rem;
      height: 5rem;
      z-index: 2;
      top: 10%;
      left: 80%;
      right: 0;
      transform-origin: top;
    }
    
    .follow_cursor::after {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      top: 100%;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: white;
      z-index: 3;
      width: 5rem;
      height: 5rem;
    }
    
    .cursor {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- this div need to be fixed -->
  <div class="follow_cursor"></div>
  <div class="cursor"></div>
</body>
<script>
  let cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
  let main = document.querySelector(".main");
  const follow = document.querySelector(".follow_cursor");
  const origR = follow.getBoundingClientRect()
  document.onmousemove = (e) => {
    let x = e.pageX;
    let y = e.pageY;
    cursor.style.transform = "translate3d(" + x + "px, " + y + "px, 0)"

    // calculate distance and angle.
    let check = parseFloat(x);
    let xf = origR.left+origR.width/2;
    let yf = origR.top;
    // distance to cursor from follow
    let dist = Math.sqrt((xf - x) * (xf - x) +
    (yf - y) * (yf - y))
    var angle = 0
    // get the rotation angle
    angle = 90 + Math.atan2(yf - y, xf - x) * 180 / Math.PI

    follow.style.transform = "rotateZ(" + angle + "deg) scaleY(" + (dist/origR.height/2) + ")";
  };
</script>

</html>
```